# Python: count total no of non-zero pixels which are not not present with respect to another image

Tags: python, image-processing, pixel

I have 2 binary images.

1. I want to find total number of non-zero pixels in image 'B' which was not present in image 'A'.
2. Also want to count total number of non-zero pixel vanished from image 'A' with respect to image 'B'

Here is an graphical example
[(Each white dot represent a pixel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWw4n.jpg)

As in my case it should be 2 for question 1.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use PIL import image to get your images to numpy arrays, then either use numpy/pandas logic to get your answers or convert them to lists and use my logic below:

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
'''
pic1 = Image.open("foo1.jpg")
pic2 = Image.open("foo2.jpg")

a1 = numpy.array(pic1)
a2 = numpy.array(pic2)

pixel1 = a1.tolist()
pixel2 = a2.tolist()
'''
mat1 = [
    [0,0,1],
    [0,1,0],
    [1,0,0]
]
mat2 = [
    [1,0,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,1]
]

result = []
for rownum,row in enumerate(mat1):
    addrow=[]
    for ind,item in enumerate(row):
        if mat1[rownum][ind]==0 and mat2[rownum][ind]==1:
            addrow.append("question_1")
        elif mat1[rownum][ind]==1 and mat2[rownum][ind]==0:
            addrow.append("question_2")
        else:
            addrow.append("_")
    result.append(addrow)
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved using your hints. But, I can't make I binary image into list of lists. Help me to find out that. I am not a developer...